# Get a Variable directly from function Python

Tags: python, function, variables

i want to work with the variable "sets" after the function has been called.

How can i do this?

```
sets = 0
  
def search_str(monatsabrechnung, d1):
       with open(monatsabrechnung, 'r') as file:
           
           content = file.read()
   
           if lastDay == heute and ja == 1:
               sets = 1         
           
           else:
               pass
               

search_str(monatsabrechnung, d1)


print(sets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to modify a variable in a function, which is originally defined outside a function. This is a variable scoping problem. Do check [this awesome article](https://towardsdatascience.com/but-its-not-declared-40501fb1e943) to get an understanding of how variable scopes work in python.

Back to your code, the issue here is that even though you run the function to modify the variable `sets` to 1, python goes back to the outer scope where `sets` were set to 0.

```py
sets = 0             #<-- outer scope
def search_str():
    ...              #do something
    sets = 1         #<-- inner scope              

search_str()
print(sets)          #back to outer scope

# 0
```

#### Solution 1: Pass as a parameter and return

You will have to pass the variable as a parameter to the function and then return it as follows -

```py
sets = 0
def search_str(sets):        #<-- pass as paramter
    ...                      #do something
    sets = 1                 #<-- modify
    return sets         

output = search_str(sets)    #<-- save the output
print(output)

# 1
```

> **TIP:** If your function is already returning another output, you can actually return, store and unpack multiple return values at once -
>
> 1. In your return statement, return everything you need `return x, y, sets`
> 2. Then, while calling use - `X, Y, sets = search_str(...)`

#### Solution 2: Set scope to global

**If passing a parameter and returning is not an option for you**, the scope of the variable has to be made global -

```py
sets = 0
def search_str():
    global sets           #<-- set the scope to global
    ...                   #do something
    sets = 1
               
search_str()
print(sets)

# 1
```

---

**EDIT**: As an additional pointer, as Matthias points out in his comments correctly, global scoping is usually avoided as it can cause a lot of problems if not careful.

Here is a great StackOverflow thread detailing [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/4755954)

Comment: Thanks i used your 2. Answer ! Works like a charm!
i didnt thought about using the global scope..

Comment: You use `global` now because it seems to be easier. You should really try to avoid this.

Comment: agreed, i have mentioned the disclaimer as well as a link which OP should read to know the issues with using `global` scope

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I saw that and I thank you for it. The comment was meant for Sn0w3y.

Answer (score 0):

Return the new value of `sets` from the function. If the `if` statement is true, then return `1`, otherwise return the same value as before. To be able to return the old value you should add it as a parameter to the function.

```
sets = 0

def search_str(monatsabrechnung, d1, sets):
    with open(monatsabrechnung, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        if lastDay == heute and ja == 1:
            current_sets = 1
        else:
            current_sets = sets
    return current_sets

sets = search_str(monatsabrechnung, d1, sets)
```

Don't use `global` if you don't have to. You get side-effects and the code is less reusable.